# Was the character 蹦 (in 蹦极 "bungee jumping") designed to look like people bungee jumping?

Tags: characters, etymology, glyph-origin

I find myself fascinated by the character

## [蹦](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E8%B9%A6)

in the word [蹦极](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%B9%A6%E6%9E%81) (meaning "bungee jumping").  It combines:

- the radical [足](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%B6%B3) (meaning "foot"), in the character [跳](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%B7%B3) meaning "jump";
- the radical [山](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B1%B1) meaning "mountain"; and
- the character [朋](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%9C%8B) meaning "friends", as in [朋友](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%9C%8B%E5%8F%8B).

It's as if the character was deliberately designed to resemble friends jumping from a mountain.  I'm hoping this thought can be verified or contradicted.

**Question**: Was the character 蹦 (in 蹦极 "bungee jumping") designed to look like people bungee jumping?

Comment: "bungee jumping" is transliterated as  "笨豬跳"  http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/43239/ in Cantonese. And I think it is the best name for this 'sport'

Comment: 蹦極 is a very nice transliteration, as it literally means *jump extreme*.

Comment: @ droooze Yeah, but it is not as funny as the Cantonese transliteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a cute mnemonic, but not how characters work.

- 「蹦」does not specifically mean *bungee jumping*, it just means *hopping/jumping/skipping*, e.g. 蹦蹦跳跳 (*skippity-skip*).
- Identify clearly what each component does in a character, and **don't recursively decompose characters**.「蹦」only contains two components:

  - Semantic component「足」(*foot > actions to do with feet/legs*)
  - Phonetic component「崩」**bēng**

    - Don't recursively decompose this into「山」and「朋」! These don't contribute anything direct to「蹦」.
    - 「崩」**bēng** doesn't contribute anything apart from sound. If you must know the composition of「崩」, its meaning is *to collapse*, metaphorically hinted with「山」(*a mountain collapsing*), and its phonetic part is「朋」**péng**.

---

Sadly, there are no friends and no mountains, but happily no collapsing in「蹦」. Stay safe!